# Storing 'ties' for Contests in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to determine if there a "low cost" optimization for the following query. We've implemented a system whereby 'tickets' earn 'points' and thus can be ranked. In order to support analytical type of queries, we store the rank of every ticket and wether the ticket is tied along with the ticket.

I've found that, at scale, storing the is_tied field is very slow. I'm attempting to run the scenario below on a set of "tickets" that is about 20-75k tickets.

I'm hoping that someone can help identify why and offer some help.

We're on postgres 9.3.6

Here's a simplified ticket table schema:

```
ogs_1=> \d api_ticket
                                             Table "public.api_ticket"
            Column            |           Type           |                        Modifiers                        
------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id                           | integer                  | not null default nextval('api_ticket_id_seq'::regclass)
 status                       | character varying(3)     | not null
 points_earned                | integer                  | not null
 rank                         | integer                  | not null
 event_id                     | integer                  | not null
 user_id                      | integer                  | not null
 is_tied                      | boolean                  | not null
Indexes:
    "api_ticket_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "api_ticket_4437cfac" btree (event_id)
    "api_ticket_e8701ad4" btree (user_id)
    "api_ticket_points_earned_idx" btree (points_earned)
    "api_ticket_rank_idx" btree ("rank")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "api_ticket_event_id_598c97289edc0e3e_fk_api_event_id" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES api_event(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
(user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Here's the query that I'm executing:

```
UPDATE api_ticket t SET is_tied = False
                WHERE t.event_id IN (SELECT id FROM api_event WHERE status = 'c');
UPDATE api_ticket t SET is_tied = True
                  FROM (
                    SELECT event_id, rank
                    FROM api_ticket tt
                    WHERE event_id in (SELECT id FROM api_event WHERE status = 'c')
                      AND tt.status <> 'x'
                    GROUP BY rank, event_id
                    HAVING count(*) > 1
                  ) AS tied_tickets
                WHERE t.rank = tied_tickets.rank AND
                  tied_tickets.event_id = t.event_id;
```

Here's the explain on a set of about 35k rows:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on api_ticket t  (cost=3590.01..603570.21 rows=157 width=128)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3590.01..603570.21 rows=157 width=128)
         ->  Subquery Scan on tied_tickets  (cost=2543.31..2556.18 rows=572 width=40)
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2543.31..2550.46 rows=572 width=8)
                     Filter: (count(*) > 1)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..2539.02 rows=572 width=8)
                           ->  Index Scan using api_event_status_idx1 on api_event  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4)
                                 Index Cond: ((status)::text = 'c'::text)
                           ->  Index Scan using api_ticket_4437cfac on api_ticket tt  (cost=0.55..2524.99 rows=572 width=8)
                                 Index Cond: (event_id = api_event.id)
                                 Filter: ((status)::text <> 'x'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on api_ticket t  (cost=1046.70..1050.71 rows=1 width=92)
               Recheck Cond: (("rank" = tied_tickets."rank") AND (event_id = tied_tickets.event_id))
               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1046.70..1046.70 rows=1 width=0)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on api_ticket_rank_idx  (cost=0.00..26.65 rows=708 width=0)
                           Index Cond: ("rank" = tied_tickets."rank")
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on api_ticket_4437cfac  (cost=0.00..1019.79 rows=573 width=0)
                           Index Cond: (event_id = tied_tickets.event_id)
```